# jQuery tabs widget display issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having difficulty with the rendering of a jQuery tabs widget. In [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cvh2013/JWgRB/1/) Fiddle you will see two images. If you click the Professional Advisers image, a tabs widget is displayed. If you click on the Industry widget, a jQuery modal dialog is rendered.

The problem is how the tabs widget displays - it should open neatly in an area below the images, as does the modal dialog. I'm unsure whether it's a CSS issue (I've tried styling the #tabs element in various ways without success) or whether I need to shuffle my s around (I;'ve tried putting the #tabs div inside the professional advisers div without success).

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="professional-advisers-image">
    <div class="circle hovershadow advisers advisers-box-shadow text">Professional
        advisers</div>
</a>
<a href="#" id="industry-image">
    <div class="circle hovershadow industry industry-box-shadow">Industry</div>
</a>

<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Law firms</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Accounting and audit firms</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Management consultants and economists</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button id="closeTabs">X</button>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Law firm text goes here</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Accounting and audit firm text goes here</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Management consultants and economists text goes here.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="industry-dialog" class="dialog" title="Industry">Industry text goes here</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#tabs").tabs().hide();
$("#professional-advisers-image").click(function () {
$("#tabs").toggle();
});

$("#closeTabs").click(function () {
$("#tabs").hide();
});

$("#industry-dialog").dialog({
autoOpen: false
});
$("#industry-image").click(function () {
$("#industry-dialog").dialog("option", "modal", true);
$("#industry-dialog").dialog("option", "height", "auto");
$("#industry-dialog").dialog("option", "width", 600);
$("#industry-dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

**CSS**

```
.circle {
width: 220px;
height: 220px;
border-radius: 50%;
border: 2px solid #fff;
float: left;
display: inline-block;
/* text styling for circles - see also the .text style below */
font-size: 35px;
color: #FFF;
line-height: 220px;
text-align: center;
font-family: Ubuntu, sans-serif;
}
#dialog #tabs {
font-family:'Istok Web', sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 1.8em;
}
.advisers {
background: #5E2750;
margin-left: 28%;
margin-right: 13%;
}
.advisers-box-shadow {
box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #5E2750
}
.industry {
background: #DD4814;
}
.industry-box-shadow {
box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #DD4814
}
.hovershadow:hover {
box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 4px #AEA79F
}
.text {
/* used by professional advisers circle */
line-height: 40px;
padding-top: 70px;
height: 150px
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a clearing div after your circles:

http://jsfiddle.net/JWgRB/2/

```
<a href="#" id="professional-advisers-image">
    <div class="circle hovershadow advisers advisers-box-shadow text">Professional
        advisers</div>
</a>
<a href="#" id="industry-image">
    <div class="circle hovershadow industry industry-box-shadow">Industry</div>
</a>

<div style="clear: both;"></div>

<div id="tabs">
```